# avoid repetition of "several"

Tags: idiomatic-language

Consider these

> my team has several listening teachers, several speaking teachers, several reading teachers and several writing teachers.
>
> my team has several listening teachers, a few of speaking teachers, multiple reading teachers and some writing teachers.
>
> my team has several different teachers for listening, speaking, reading and writing.

The first one is bad because of repeating of "**several**", the others are trying to avoid that repetition. Does those two sound natural to native speakers?

Comment: Do you need to include *several* at all?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is both repetitive and annoying to use *several* so many times.

However, I do not think your second sentence is a good replacement because *a few* and *some* have slightly different implications and connotations that may not be desirable in your situation.

The last sentence seems best to me as a native speaker because it is obvious that each verb are referring to a distinct group of several teachers, but you don't have to *say* it each time. It also sounds much more natural.

Hope this helps!